# How to design a xml file to display in more screen

Tags: android

I'm new android programmer, I designed a page screen of 4". I've initialized with "dp" unit of measurement.
but when I run my project in screen of 10" or 7" or 3"2 components go wrong.
I learned dp is for all of screen, but I don't know why my page not be set to all of screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could include any code of your XML file, that would be very helpful.
Aside from that, I believe you haven't set android:layout_width and android:layout_height so you are getting odd looking sizes for the other display sizes of you XML.
Add

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to your `<RelativeLayout>`

e.g.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
    >
```

If you do in fact have this or it does not help with your issue
, then please respond with an example of your code.

Comment: I used Linearlayout and  i used android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: If you could give me the code of your XML in your question, that would be very appreciated. Simply copy and paste it here, you can redact anything you don't want people to see.

Answer (score 0):

my xml file is here, but I set visibility of one linearlayout to gone
and when user touch button the linearlayout will be visible and another linearlayout will be gone

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
      android:background="@drawable/darirann"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
  <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/layoutTerm"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:visibility="visible">
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp">
     <LinearLayout 
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/firstpageabout" />
       </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLoad"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#114E7D"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="ادامه"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/layoutData"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:visibility="gone">
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spState"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
   <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spCity"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <Button
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#114E7D"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="مرحله ی بعد" />

   <Button
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#840101"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="دریافت نسخه ی جدید این برنامه" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAds"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
```